# Collection<PSObject> to CSV output

Tags: c#, powershell, psobject

Is there a nice  way to convert `Collection<PSObject>` to CSV output?

```
Collection<PSObject> psResult = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Tried `pipeline.ToCsv();`
Also `psResult.ToCsv()`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think there is no way out of serializing your PSObjects. Adding an overload to ToString() to the class and separating each field with a comma (you could use reflection to avoid adding each field manually) is an option.

Comment: Why not add an `Export-Csv` cmdlet to the `pipeline` instead?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thought of that.. Export-Csv requires path

Comment: @AndrasSebö Tried google.. have you :)

Comment: ConvertTo-Csv may be the solution then :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Nice! works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849878.aspx) to your `pipeline`.

The `Collection<PSObject>` returned will consist of comma-separated strings, easily converted to `IEnumerable<string>` or `string[]`